# how to pass custom parameter from identity server to client

Tags: asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, identityserver3, identityserver4

I am working on identity server 4. I want to pass additional parameter from identity server to client. I am using Hybrid Grant Type and using openid connect options.

I see that there are some acrvalues. Should i use it? How can I add claims from identity server to client?

**update**

Clients:

```
return new List<Client>()
            {
                 // Hybrid Flow
                new Client()
                {
                    ClientId = "mvcClient",
                    ClientName = "MVC Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },

                    // where to redirect to after login
                   RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },                   

                    // where to redirect to after logout
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002" },

                  AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>()
                    {
                        StandardScopes.OpenId.Name,
                        StandardScopes.Profile.Name,
                        StandardScopes.OfflineAccess.Name,
                        StandardScopes.Roles.Name,
                        StandardScopes.Email.Name,
                        "NamfusAPI",
                    },

                   AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,
                   RequireConsent = false
                },
            };
```

Scope:

```
 return new List<Scope>()
            {
                StandardScopes.OpenId, // subject id
                StandardScopes.ProfileAlwaysInclude, // first name, last name
                StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,  // requesting refresh tokens for long lived API access
                StandardScopes.Roles,
                StandardScopes.Email,
                new Scope()
                {
                    Name = "NamfusAPI",
                    Description = "Namfus API",
                    Type = ScopeType.Resource,
                    IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true,
                    Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>()
                    {
                        new ScopeClaim(ClaimTypes.Name, true),
                        new ScopeClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, true),

                    }
                }
        };
```

my web form client has this:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "oidc",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                Authority = "http://localhost:5000", // check in client side [not on priority]
                ClientId = "mvcClient",
                ClientSecret = "secret",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:5002",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:5002",
                ResponseType = "code id_token token",
                Scope = "openid profile NamfusAPI offline_access roles email",
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { NameClaimType ="name" },


                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {

                    SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                    {
                        var claims_to_exclude = new[]
                        {
                            "aud", "iss", "nbf", "exp", "nonce", "iat", "at_hash"
                        };


                        var claims_to_keep = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims
                                             .Where(x => false == claims_to_exclude.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();
                        claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken != null)
                        {
                            claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                            var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient("http://localhost:5000/connect/userinfo",
                                new HttpClientHandler());
                            var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);
                            var userInfoClaims = userInfoResponse.Claims
                                .Where(x => x.Type != "sub") // filter sub since we're already getting it from id_token
                                .Select(x => new Claim(x.Type, x.Value));
                            claims_to_keep.AddRange(userInfoClaims);
                        }
                        var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
                            "name", "role");
                        ci.AddClaims(claims_to_keep);

                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket(
                            ci, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties
                        );
                    },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                    {
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                        {
                            var id_token = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token")?.Value;
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = id_token;
                        }

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: What is the parameter? And where you do you want the value?

Comment: I have added a view with a drop down of user's roles. I want to pass selected parameter from server to client and based on that role, i want to show client home page.

Comment: @BrockAllen something like this. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/841. The answer is also from you in the link.

Comment: I'm still confused -- do you want a custom claim in the response? Or do you want to put a custom value in the protocol response?

Comment: I want to put a custom value in the response and get it on client. process is user will login and go to IS, after authentication he will select the role e.g teacher ( from his roles list, and redirected to client. on client, i need this value and show client for that role. second step is that user will select another role and client will change ( go in ) that role e.g student. I have asp.net web form client. and identity server is in core Identity server rc 3. and I have web api as well.

Comment: @BrockAllen any suggestion?

Comment: You can always control the user claims returned in the token, but we don't currently have a way to augment the authorize response itself. Open an issue on the issue tracker for this, please, if you'd like to see this added as a feature.